# Apply v-focus to the first input field on a page

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, autofocus

I've a Vue component in which I'm trying to autofocus the first field using `v-focus`. But my problem is, I've dynamic components that will be included at the top of the page. So in that case how can I apply autofocus to dynamically included component?

Comment: Would you mind supplying some pseudo code demonstrating your issue? We would be able to better assist you this way.

Comment: say, I've 3 inputs `input1, input2 & input3`. in my component the order of the inputs is `input1 & input2`, so the first element is `input1`. Based on some conditions I add `input3` on top of `input1 & input2`, so, now the first component will be `input3`. so how can I apply the autofocus to the first element all the time?

Comment: Are you using a custom directive or an actual [`v-focus` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-focus)?

Comment: I'm using v-focus, and the input is added on page load, not in a loop

Comment: Can you please supply a CodePen outlining your request? The logic would be the same in a loop or not. You need to use refs.

Comment: I implemented using `refs` it worked. Thanks.

Comment: No problem.  If my solution helped you, please feel free to mark as the accepted answer and add an upvote :)  Thank you!

Comment: @TejaD Can you post your answer, kind sir? That would be a big help! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

They key is to set `ref` on all your `input`s to the same string like this:

```
<input type="text" ref="myInputs"/>
```

Then you will have access to an array called `this.$refs.myInputs` inside an event handler.

So you just need to do

```
this.$refs.myInputs[0].focus();
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.myInputs[0].focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div v-for="index in 3" :key="index">
      <input ref="myInputs" type="text" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell how you're adding the input(s) to the `DOM`, without any pseudo code from you, but this is one way to do it..

[[CodePen mirror](https://codepen.io/oze4/details/bJMjyZ)]

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    inputs: ["firstName", "lastName"]
  },
  watch: {
    inputs() {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        this.focusFirstInput();
      });
    }
  },
  methods: {
    focusFirstInput() {
      let first = this.inputs[0];
      let firstInput = this.$refs[first][0];
      firstInput.focus();
    },
    handleClick() {
      this.inputs.push("newInput");
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.focusFirstInput();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <div v-for="(input, index) in inputs" :key="index">
      <input :ref="input" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="button" @click="handleClick">Click to add input</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer on [Laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/vue/vue-set-focus-to-input-created-by-v-for?page=1) and it worked for me. All I did was insert the code below in my dynamic form field.

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
  let index = this.items.length - 1;
  let input = this.$refs.title[index];
  input.focus();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <ul v-for="item in items">
    <li>
      <input :ref="'title'" v-model="item.title">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button v-on:click="addItem">Add Item</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
let app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
      {title: 'Apple'},
      {title: 'Orange'},
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    addItem(){
       this.items.push({title: "Pineapple"});
       this.$nextTick(() => {
         let index = this.items.length - 1;
         let input = this.$refs.title[index];
         input.focus();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Note: make sure to add `:ref="'title'"` into your dynamic form field.

Credits to the original author of the solution.